# Reverse proxy IIS 10 config for socket.io not working

Tags: socket.io, reverse-proxy, iis-10

i have face problem when i use reverse proxy at IIS 10 for my exprees.js, i got 404 error
for socket.io

here my config

```
<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:7000/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
```

response i get
Cannot GET /Rejected-By-UrlScan

the error is
[image]

Comment: Can you see what FRT says about those 404 errors? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: for this server they dont install FRT, i dont have authorize to install that to iis

Comment: Either you reproduce the same issue on another machine that you can perform troubleshooting there, or little you can do to resolve the issue because the basic troubleshooting methods are not even available. Let the server administrators know that simple fact. Besides, they shouldn't have UrlScan running on any IIS machines today, https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/iis-docs/issues/418 as it has been obsolete.

Comment: Could you please provide more detailed error information about this error code?